# Using atoi with char

Tags: c, atoi

Is there a way of converting a char into a string in C?

I'm trying to do so like this:

```
   char *array;

   array[0] = '1';

   int x = atoi(array);

   printf("%d",x);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
   char arr[] = "X";
   int x;
   arr[0] = '9';
   x = atoi(arr);
   printf("%d",x);
```

Comment: This is rather excessive for a single char.  Additional variables, arrays, null terminators are all unnecessary.

Answer (score 34):

```
char c = '1';
int x = c - '0';
printf("%d",x);
```

Comment: Simplest answer without having to use any intermediary buffers

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to convert a numerical char to an int, just use character arithmetic to subtract the ASCII code:

```
int x = myChar - '0';
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to allocate memory to the string, and then null terminate.

```
char *array;

array = malloc(2);
array[0] = '1';
array[1] = '\0';

int x = atoi(array);

printf("%d",x);
```

Or, easier:

```
char array[10];

array = "1";

int x = atoi(array);

printf("%d",x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a character to a string via the following:

```
char string[2];
string[0] = '1';
string[1] = 0;
```

Strings end with a NUL character, which has the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

A declaration of the atoi function is (it awaits a "string"):

```
int atoi(const char * str)
```

If you are going to use it with a single character, you will get a **segmentation fault**, because the function tries to read the memory until it finds the **'\0'**!

E. g. try this:

```
char char_digit = '5';
char string_for_atoi[2] = { char_digit, '\0' };

int number = atoi(string_for_atoi);
```