# Reading single-digit integers from a string

Tags: c

I want to read integers from a file like this:

```
9 5  1847
6    9 5
 87     
2   48  1
7 1 5 4 2
6  17   8
   95  
4 6    8 
5192  7 4
```

For example 1,8,4,7 are to be taken as different numbers.

I tried this way:

```
 #define MAXLINE 1024

 void readFile(FILE *file){
     char line [MAXLINE];
     int j;
     while(fgets(line,MAXLINE,file)!=NULL){
         for(j=0;j<9;j++){              
             int a = atoi(&line[j]);
             printf("%d \n",a);         
         }      
     }
 }
```

But it is reading 1847 as only one number.

Comment: What has this to do with haskell?

Comment: Are all the number meant to be single-digit numbers?  Is the `87` to be intepreted as `8` and `7`?  Also, what is a `File *`?  The standard type is a `FILE *`.

Comment: Sorry the title was from other question. Yes to the question. I know that it's FILE and not File, I was wrong when I was writing the question.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915725/using-atoi-with-char

Comment: @Aleksandar Someone inexplicably edited that to say Haskell.. which was then approved in the edit review queue. Not sure why that was.

Comment: @Collin: the original title included Haskell; someone edited from an out-of-date version of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
enum { MAXLINE = 1024 };

void readFile(FILE *file)
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != 0)
    {
        char *str = line;
        int j;
        int pos;
        while (sscanf(str, "%1d%n", &j, &pos) == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n", j);
            str += pos;
        }
    }
}
```

The `%1d` part of the format reads a single digit (but also skips blanks).  The `%n` is in C89 and reports the position where the scan is in the string; it is not counted as a conversion (hence the comparison with 1).

Comment: why not fscanf here instead fgets/sscanf?

Comment: It would be possible to use `fscanf()`; I prefer `fgets()` plus `sscanf()` because if I want to report an error, I've got the whole line to include in the report, rather than some truncated residue left behind by `fscanf()`.  Also because the question was using `fgets()` and then parsing the line, of course.

Comment: And if I want don't want to skip blanks? I have to know where they are. Thanks

Comment: If you need to know about the blanks, then you step through the string, one character at a time, processing blanks in one way and converting single digits to numbers with `int a = line[i] - '0';`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C are NULL-terminated. This means, if you give a pointer to a function expecting a string, everything from this memory location up to the first NULL-byte is considered part of the string.

Having said that, you need to treat each character separately. First you need to check whether the character actually is a number. As suggested by Jonathan Leffler, the C standard guarantees that '0'..'9' are a consecutive range in the charset:

> ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §5.2.1 Character sets: *In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.*

Hence, the following is a correct solution:

```
for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
   char c = line[j];
   if ('0' <= c || c <= '9')
       printf("%d \n", c - '0');
}
```

Instead of `c - '0'` you can also use `atoi`, but then you need to turn your char into a string again (this needs to go inside the if):

```
char[2] s = " "; // " " only serves as a placeholder.
s[0] = c;
int a = atoi(s);
```

Comment: Why not `int a = line[j] - '0';`, after checking that you are dealing with a digit?

Comment: This would be another option, if you are willing to embed the knowledge that the digits occur consecutively in the charset in your code.

Comment: It's required by the C standard that the digits 0..9 occupy successive code points in the character set.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §5.2.1 Character sets: _In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than
the value of the previous._